# How to find element in KML tree containing ':'

Tags: python, xml, kml, elementtree

Problem: can't find element with ':' - cannot run program. I found some references about [Qualified Names](http://effbot.org/zone/element-qnames.htm) but I don't know how to apply those.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree                           

kmlTree = ElementTree()                                                 
kmlTree.parse("data/history-03-08-2012.kml")                            

track = kmlTree.find(".//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}gx:Track")
```

Sample data file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<gx:Track>
<when>2012-03-10T05:52:38.564-08:00</when>
<gx:coord>16.424247 48.236804 0</gx:coord>
<when>2012-03-10T06:00:39.748-08:00</when>
<gx:coord>16.424247 48.236804 0</gx:coord>
</gx:Track>
</kml>
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    track = kmlTree.find(".//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}gx:Track")        #most interesting data is stored in this tag
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 614, in find
    return self._root.find(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 330, in find
    return ElementPath.find(self, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 186, in find
    return _compile(path).find(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
    p = Path(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
    "expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)
```

Code is working for elements without ':'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gx` is a namespace shortcut for `{http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2}`.  Take `gx:` out of the `find` and use the correct namespace:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

data = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<gx:Track>
<when>2012-03-10T05:52:38.564-08:00</when>
<gx:coord>16.424247 48.236804 0</gx:coord>
<when>2012-03-10T06:00:39.748-08:00</when>
<gx:coord>16.424247 48.236804 0</gx:coord>
</gx:Track>
</kml>
'''

kmlTree = et.fromstring(data)

track = kmlTree.find(".//{http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2}Track")
print(track)
```

#### Output

```
<Element '{http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2}Track' at 0x40cca70>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an alternate solution which uses [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

```
>>> tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> tree.xpath(".//gx:Track",namespaces={'gx':'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'})
[<Element {http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2}Track at 0x1c1e3f0>]


>>> tree.xpath("//gx:Track/*/text()",namespaces={'gx':'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'})
['2012-03-10T05:52:38.564-08:00', '16.424247 48.236804 0', '2012-03-10T06:00:39.748-08:00', '16.424247 48.236804 0']
```

I believe similar approach can be used for `ElementTree`.